# How to populate a field in a table of points with the ID of the polygon they fall within using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, gis

I am trying to use SQL Server to update a field within a table of point data with the ID of the polygon each point is located inside of. I haven't found a good example of this online and I would be grateful for any help. I am including the code I have currently even though I know it is wrong.

```
Update Points
Set Points.Loc_ID = Polygon.Area_ID 
Where GlobalID IN 
        (GlobalID IN (Select Points.GlobalID 
                      from Points
                      Join Polygon ON (Polygon.SHAPE).STIntersects(Polygon.SHAPE) = 1))
```

Comment: Some sample data and expected results could help. As could considering whether it's possible that multiple shapes contain the same point and, if so, what should happen then.

Answer (score 0):

Making a guess here as your example is a bit thin:

```
-- update Points
-- set Loc_ID = Polygon.Area_ID
select Points.geoColumn, Points.Loc_ID, Polygon.Area_ID 
from Points
join Polygon
    on Polygon.SHAPE.STContains(Points.geoColumn) = 1;
```

I've coded it as a select but the update portion is there - just uncomment that and comment out the select clause. The magic is in the join - you're looking for polygons that contain your points. So we test that as the join criteria.